# How to loop a JavaScript nodelist and apply a JavaScript style?

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, methods, nodelist

How can I get the JavaScript loop associated with the liList variable to effect the DOM whist not over-riding any other styles?

I would like my menu items to still be orange and for the first list item to hold onto the styleAbbr variable that was created in JavaScript.

```js
//JavaScript style to effect HTML abbr
var styleAbbr = document.createElement('style');
styleAbbr.type = 'text/css';
styleAbbr.innerHTML = '.myAbbr {font-style: italic; letter-spacing: .4em;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleAbbr);
document.querySelector('abbr').className = 'myAbbr';

//the JavaScript for the loop
var msg = '';
var i = 0;
var liList = document.querySelectorAll('li.menuItem');

if (i < liList.length) {
for (var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {

//liList[i].textContent gets the text form the li element in the DOM
var listWording = liList[i].textContent;

//liList.innerHTML applies my style and pushes listWording into the DOM
msg += '<li style="background: red; margin-top: 10px;">'
    + listWording
    + '</li>';
}
}

//I believe that the issue is that .innerHTML = msg.
document.getElementById('mMain').innerHTML = msg;
```

```css
ul {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    list-style: none;
    }

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e69b1e;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="mMain">
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">
            <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Ideally I would like to have my JavaScript style in its own variable and loop that into the "menuItem" class whilst not effecting any other predefined class's however I am not quite sure how I would call that variable into a loop.

```
var menuItemClass = document.createElement('style');
menuItemClass.type = 'text/css';
menuItemClass.innerHTML = '.menuStyle {background: red; margin-top: 10px;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(menuItemClass);
```

Im also aware I could have a class in my CSS do all of this and then reference that. 
However I am interested how this can be achieved in JavaScript.
Thank you.

Comment: do you want to create class dynamically and apply to each li elements which is from the existing menu li

Comment: Was trying to see how I could create the style within the JavaScript Loop, Found a solution which was my ultimate goal.

Comment: have a look in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to referencing my JavaScript defined style.

```js
var styleAbbr = document.createElement('style');
styleAbbr.type = 'text/css';
styleAbbr.innerHTML = '.myAbbr {font-style: italic; letter-spacing: .4em;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleAbbr);
document.querySelector('abbr').className = 'myAbbr';

var menuItemClass = document.createElement('style');
menuItemClass.type = 'text/css';
menuItemClass.innerHTML = '.menuStyle {background: red; margin-top: 10px;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(menuItemClass);

var msg = '';
var i = 0;
var liList = document.querySelectorAll('li.menuItem');

if (i < liList.length) {
for (var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
liList[i].className = 'menuStyle';
}
}
```

```css
ul li {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    list-style: none;
    }

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
     color: #e69b1e;
     }
```

```html
<ul id="mMain">
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">
            <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering how to add class to each `li` element created dynamically without effecting predefined. So create class according to the menu item `innerText` and take background color for the class from array defined `colors`

```js
//JavaScript style to effect HTML abbr
var styleAbbr = document.createElement('style');
styleAbbr.type = 'text/css';
styleAbbr.innerHTML = '.myAbbr {font-style: italic; letter-spacing: .4em;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleAbbr);
document.querySelector('abbr').className = 'myAbbr';

//the JavaScript for the loop
var msg = '';
var i = 0;
var liList = document.querySelectorAll('li.menuItem');
//defining background colours
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'brown', 'blue'];
var j = 0;
if (i < liList.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
    //creating class as the innerText content
    if (j >= colors.length) {
      j = 0
    }

    var menuItemClass = document.createElement('style');
    menuItemClass.type = 'text/css';
    menuItemClass.innerHTML = '.' + liList[i].innerText + ' {background: ' + colors[j] + '; margin-top: 10px;}';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(menuItemClass);
    j++;

    //liList[i].textContent gets the text form the li element in the DOM
    var listWording = liList[i].textContent;

    //liList.innerHTML applies my style and pushes listWording into the DOM
    if (i == 0) {
      msg += liList.innerHTML =
        '<li class="myAbbr ' + listWording + '">' +
        listWording +
        '</li>';
    } else {
      msg += liList.innerHTML =
        '<li class=" ' + listWording + '">' +
        listWording +
        '</li>';
    }
  }
}

//I believe that the issue is that .innerHTML = msg.
document.getElementById('mMain').innerHTML = msg;
```

```css
ul {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e69b1e;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mMain">
  <li class="menuItem">
    <a href="#">
      <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuItem">
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuItem">
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuItem">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The difficulty is that the myAbbr class should only be applied to the first menu item and the css color is overridden

Comment: make condition when `i==0` then add selected class only